# avoiding the side-effects of c()

Tags: r

In particular, the removing attributes note in `?c`

```
> x <- 1
> y <- as.integer(1)
> str(x);str(y)
 num 1
 int 1

> identical(x, y)
[1] FALSE

> str(c(x, y))
 num [1:2] 1 1

> tmp <- c(x, y)
> identical(tmp[1], tmp[2])
[1] TRUE
```

Another example (but not as relevant)

```
> tmp <- c(1, 3, 2)
> sort(tmp)
[1] 1 2 3

> tmp <- factor(tmp, levels = ordered(tmp))
> sort(tmp)
[1] 1 3 2
Levels: 1 3 2

> sort(rep(tmp, 2))
[1] 1 1 3 3 2 2
Levels: 1 3 2

> tmp1 <- c(tmp, tmp)
> sort(tmp1)
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

I ask because I have a function that takes `...` and combines 11ty-many objects (as in `tmp <- c(...)` and performs `identical` on each pair, and it currently (correctly) says `1` and `as.integer(1)` are identical which is not what I want.

Comment: oh duh. That worked well @JoshuaUlrich. Thanks! I was going to use a shorter function that you wrote, I think, as an example that recursively uses `identical` on several objects which also suffers from the same problem

Comment: Well he deleted his comment, and now I just look silly talking to myself

Comment: To assure everyone on the internet that "rawr" was not talking to themselves: my comment was, "You can't mix types in a vector. Use a list."

Comment: "Side-effects", in functional programming-speak, are anything a function does to the system state that isn't returning a value (eg the `plot` function making a plot). What you are describing aren't side-effects, its just the way some functions return values given those arguments.

Comment: `?c`:::"`c` is sometimes used for its side effect of removing attributes except names" @Spacedman

Comment: Then `?c` isn't using the term strictly. "In computer science, a function or expression is said to have a side effect if, in addition to returning a value, it also modifies some state or has an observable interaction with calling functions of the outside world." - wikipedia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atomic vectors cannot store elements of different modes. If you combine objects of different modes using `c`, all are transformed into the most general mode (character > numeric > integer > logical).

If you want to store objects of different modes, you can use lists. Here is an illustration:

Atomic vectors:

```
x <- 1
y <- 1L
str(x); str(y)
# num 1
# int 1

str(c(x, y))
# num [1:2] 1 1
```

Combine both values in a list:

```
z <- list(x, y)
str(z)
# List of 2
#  $ : num 1
#  $ : int 1

identical(z[[1]], z[[2]])
# [1] FALSE
```

Store objects in a one-element list and combine them using `c`:

```
xList <- list(x)
yList <- list(y)
zList <- c(xList, yList)
str(zList)
# List of 2
#  $ : num 1
#  $ : int 1

identical(zList[[1]], zList[[2]])
# [1] FALSE
```